# How do I use a SharePoint List as a Data Source?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm creating a VB-based application in Virtual Studio 2013, and up until now I've been testing the tables used for its operation in a local MDF file.  Obviously, I need to find a better solution for deployment as this will need to be used by multiple users.  I decided to go with a SharePoint list for ease of access and better local control. (We have SharePoint Server 2010 running)

When I try to add a SharePoint Connection in the Server Explorer, it tells me I don't have Foundation or Server installed.  Checking our corp's software request tool, I didn't find either of those.  There's a 'SharePoint Designer' option, and another that sounds promising is 'Microsoft SSIS SharePoint List Adapters with SharePoint'.  I couldn't find any info online about whether those would fit the bill.  **Would either of those serve the purpose of standing in for Foundation or Server?**  If not, I'm sure I could find a way to request Foundation but I'm sure that would add quite a bit of delay while they vet it for business use.

Also, if I install the necessary software for development on MY machine, **will those dependencies be included in the executable so my clients wouldn't have to install those SharePoint tools as well?**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access and manipulate with your sharepoint list from your code, you can look at Sharepoint CSOM. It allows you to remotely connect and proceed CRUD operations with sharepoint list.

Comment: I found this: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116646/vb-net-client-object-model-view-content-from-sharepoint-2010-wikipage

But if this is what you meant by using CSOM, it looks like it still depends on the presence of at least SharePoint Foundation.  I don't think I can import 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client' without that.